# JavaScript fetch response returning undefined

Tags: javascript, fetch

I´m trying to use fetch to load some server data. Here is the code:

```
fetch('/user', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        data: 'test'
    })
})
.then(response => {
        if (response.status !== 200) {
            console.log('Fetch status not OK');
        }
        else {
            console.log('Fetch ok');
            console.log(response); // Undefined here
        }
    })
.catch(error => {
        console.log('network error');
    });
```

At the browser (network) I can see the response payload being returned from server, but my response contains `undefined`. I can imagine this shall be simple, but I can´t find out what is happening here.

Comment: `/api`? What is your endpoint? Where in the `api` folder are you trying to access?

Comment: There are also no brackets on that `else` statement

Comment: @4castle, sure. Corrected.

Comment: Response *cannot* be undefined, you'd get a type error when you tried to check the status property at the start of the conditional. You'd never make it to the else branch.

Comment: `// Undefined here` - no it isn't - but you haven't accessed the actual response body yet ... i.e. `response.json()` would seem to be appropriate for your code - be aware that your `.then` results in undefined as you aren't returning anything from it - so, later in the promise chain is where you'll be getting undefined (this isn't ALL your code, right)

Comment: This is everything in my fetch. I think I'm misunderstanding fetch. Can someone please advice the correct way of using it....

Answer (score 5):

I was having a similar issue, where `response.body` was returning `undefined`. Not strictly the same as the OP's code, but I'm guessing this may have been the same issue, and also searching led me here, so posting my answer.

This happens because the body has not been read yet, only the response headers have arrived. The correct way of accessing the response body is:

```
fetch('/user').then((resp) => resp.json().then((body) => console.log(body)))
```

The various ways of reading the body (as text, JSON, etc...) are [documented here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response).